# Error in spec file.Tests failing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

> Controller code

```
var dashboardApp = angular.module('do.dashboard', [])

 dashboardApp.controller('developerSummaryController', ['$scope',     '$filter', '$routeParams', 'developerSummaryService',
function ($scope, $filter, $routeParams, summaryBoardService) {

    $scope.group = {};

    var _getStatusText = function (statusValue) {
        return statusValue <= 33 ? 'RED' : (statusValue <= 66 ? 'YELLOW' : (statusValue <= 100 ? 'GREEN' : 'GREEN'))
    }

    var _parseSummaryData = function (summaryValue) {


        summaryValue.OverallStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.OverallStatus);
        summaryValue.BuildUTStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.UnitTesting);
        summaryValue.CodeQualityStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.CodeQuality);
        summaryValue.Deploy.DevStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.Deploy.Dev);
        summaryValue.Deploy.QAStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.Deploy.QA);
        summaryValue.Deploy.ProdStatusText = _getStatusText(summaryValue.Deploy.Production);

        angular.forEach(summaryValue.Components, function (componentValue, componentKey) {

            componentValue.OverallStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.OverallStatus);
            componentValue.BuildUTStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.UnitTesting);
            componentValue.CodeQualityStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.CodeQuality);
            componentValue.Deploy.DevStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.Deploy.Dev);
            componentValue.Deploy.QAStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.Deploy.QA);
            componentValue.Deploy.ProdStatusText = _getStatusText(componentValue.Deploy.Production);

            componentValue.BuildTime = $filter('date')(componentValue.BuildTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a');
        });

        return summaryValue;
    }

    summaryBoardService.getSummaryBoardData($routeParams.groupName).then(
        function success(response) {
            $scope.group = _parseSummaryData(response.data);
        }, function error(reason) {
            console.log(reason);
        });
} ]);
```

> Spec

```
describe('developerSummaryController', function () {
var scope, ctrl, mockSefService, $timeout;

beforeEach(module('do.dashboard'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$timeout_) {

    mockSefService = jasmine.createSpyObj('developerSummaryService', ['getSummaryBoardData']);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    mockSefService.getSummaryBoardData.and.returnValue($q.when(
        {data: { Name: 'Client Management', OverallStatus: 15.777499999999998, CodeQuality: 10.5, UnitTesting: 28.5, CodeCoverage: 8.3325 }}

    ));

    ctrl = $controller('developerSummaryController', {
        $scope: scope,
        developerSummaryService: mockSefService,
        $routeParams: { id: 'Client Management' }
    });
}));


it('controller should not be null', function () {
    expect(ctrl).not.toBe(null);
});

it('should set the scope data with route parameter', function () {
    expect(scope.groupName).toEqual('Client Management');
});


it('should call the service method and set the scope data', function () {
    expect(mockSefService.getSummaryBoardData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(scope.group.Name).toEqual('Client Management');
    expect(scope.group.OverallStatus).toEqual(15.777499999999998);
    expect(scope.group.CodeQuality).toEqual(10.5);
});

});
```

> Here the Controller i have written tests the last two are failing always can anyone tel the solution or what i might doing wrong here.
>   here the controller file having a Json which is called form a service i am only creating unit tests for the controller.

Comment: expect(scope.group.Name).toEqual('Client Management');
    expect(scope.group.OverallStatus).toEqual(15.777499999999998);
    expect(scope.group.CodeQuality).toEqual(10.5);

Comment: here the error is throwing